# passbook web service not registering device

Tags: php, apache, passbook

Im able to create passes and sign them, I'm trying to implement a web service to register the passes and devices .
i have implemented the web service end points to take care of POST, DELETE and GET

I'm having issues with the pass unable to register:

```
if (strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) === "POST"
    && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'])
    && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], 'ApplePass') === 0
    && $request[2] === "devices"
    && $request[4] === "registrations") {

    $auth_key = str_replace('ApplePass ', '', $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']);
```

$_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] is returning null so i wont enter the register a pass function

i have installed the ssl certificate from godaddy in my cPanel manager 
anything else to be done with the server?

im testing my web service using Echo (mac store)

also i ve been creating passes and nothing is showing in my logs

any help will be appreciated

new to php and passbook

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you are not correctly getting hold of the Authorisation header.

If you are using Apache, then most PHP/Apache distributions come with a [built in function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php) `apache__request_headers()`.

You can use this as follows:

```
$headers = apache_request_headers();

if (strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) === "POST"
    && isset($headers['Authorization'])
    && strpos($headers['Authorization'], 'ApplePass') === 0
    && $request[2] === "devices"
    && $request[4] === "registrations") {

    $auth_key = str_replace('ApplePass ', '', $headers['Authorization']);
```

If your distribution does not have the `apache_request_headers` function you can replicate it.

```
if (!function_exists('apache_request_headers')) {
    function apache_request_headers() {
        foreach($_SERVER as $key=>$value) {
            if (substr($key,0,5)=="HTTP_") {
                $key=str_replace(" ","-",ucwords(strtolower(str_replace("_"," ",substr($key,5)))));
                $out[$key]=$value;
            }else{
                $out[$key]=$value;
            }
        }
        return $out;
    }
}
```

For Nginx then add the following `fastcgi_param` to your config, then you can access the variable with `$_SERVER['Authorization']`.

```
fastcgi_param  Authorization      $http_authorization;
```

Comment: also looking into apache_request_headers(); i found that rewriting the .htaccess you can access the $_SERVER(AUTHORIZATION)<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>